# scope.$on $mdMenuOpen is not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to listen for the `$mdMenuOpen` event in my directive.

```
.directive('mdPreventFocus', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, $mdOpenMenu) {
            element.on('click', function () {

                console.log(scope);

                scope.$on('$mdMenuOpen', function(ev, element) {
                    console.log('open');
                });

            })
        }
    }
})


<md-menu md-position-mode="target-right target" md-offset="0 42">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button rounded dtp-btn-ok" ng-click="$mdMenu.open($event);" md-prevent-focus>
        <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
    </md-button>
    <md-menu-content class="person-popup contact-popup">
        <md-card md-theme-watch>
            <md-card-title>
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span class="md-headline">Headline</span>
                    <span class="md-subhead">Subhead informatie</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                <md-button title="Title informatie" class="md-icon-button icon-margin">
                    <i class="material-icons">phone</i>
                </md-button>
                <md-button title="Title informatie" class="md-icon-button icon-margin">
                    <i class="material-icons">email</i>
                </md-button>
                <md-button title="Title informatie" class="md-icon-button icon-margin">
                    <i class="material-icons" >forward</i>
                </md-button>
            </md-card-actions>
        </md-card>
    </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

When I click the md-button I do see the `console.log(scope)` output but the `scope.$on` doesn't do anything.

If I check the `scope` in the console I do see `$mdOpenMenu: ƒ`

Also I can log the `scope.$id` which returns a value, but if I log `scope.$mdMenuIsOpen` I get a undefined. Which means the mdMenu is not open, otherwise it would be true. But in my UI the menu is open.

Any ideas why my `scope.$on` isn't working?

// EDIT //

It seems that only the first time I open the menu the `scope.on('$mdMenuOpen')` doesn't work. If I open the menu again I do see the console.log message.

// EDIT 2 //

I replicated my Code on a Codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmQNzv and there it does seem  to work as intended. So I'm going see what the problem in my code is.

Comment: `$on` in ang is related to broadcast/emit . do you mean `on`, if you can share a sample repo can help you.

Comment: No, I mean $on. Since I'm trying to catch a broadcast in my angularJS application.

Comment: is it really need to put `element.on('click', function() {....` to start the `$on` listener?

Comment: Hm,  thanks for pointing  that out. It wasn't necessary to put it inside the click. Seems the listener is working now.